# About a 50 ohm stripline: freq range 0 to 18 GHz

Tags: impedance-matching, microstrip

I have a shielded box stripline as shown below:

```
|-------------------------|
|         ___W___         |
|        |_______|t       |                 
|                         |
|-------------------------|
```

[image]

box dimension: 4.3cm x 1 cm x 6 cm. Y x Z x X

Now, the coax(the 50 ohm SMA) is touching the end of the stripline. the dimension of the stripline is width: 1.44cm, thickness: 0.048 and length is 6 cm.

We did 20* cut both side so that 50 ohm is uniformly on each side.

However, we didn't find any good result as expected. From theory we find the stripline should behave as 50 ohm line but it is not as shown below:

the result:

S11 maximum is -5 dB where we are expected it should be below -30 dB. It is not.

Now, anyone if encountered or made any 50 ohm stripline and also tested in VNA, please help me. What is the problem with the structure? The experiment and the simulation is same, S11 is maximum is -5 dB which means impedance mismatch. Please help. I can upload the S11 if necessary. BTW, the frequency range is 0 to 18 GHz.

thanks in advance.

material: copper as strpline and AL shielded box.

Comment: Far too wide - recheck your calculations.

Comment: Is the shielded box meant to act as the return path for the stripline or just as the boundary for the simulation? If it's the simulation boundary, where are the ground planes of your structure? How does the coax outer conductor contact the stripline ground (box or ground plane)?

Comment: yeah, the gnd is touching gnd of sma, so the box is the gnd or return path.

Comment: 18 GHz might be too much for simple FR4.

Comment: You should do a modal analysis in your simulator to determine whether this box you have made is actually supporting a stripline mode or if there is a more dominant CPW mode propagating in this structure. Look at the E-field distribution. Check the boundary conditions in your simulation, and check whether the outer conductor on your coax is well soldered to your aluminum enclosure.

Comment: So this is a stripline in air? It probably acts more like a coaxial or coplanar structure. A stripline is only supposed to couple to planes above and below, but your side wall spacing is smaller than the stripline width. As Captainj says, look at the E-fields.

Comment: Okay, @Captainj2001 I think higher modes are going in but we found same things in the experiment too. And the Coax is actually touching, we did sholdering but its showing bad S11 (more reflection).

Comment: @mng I think it is a TEM case not coplanar case.

Comment: @gman You need to look at the E-field in simulation to be sure you're not exciting a CPW mode, post a picture of the fields in the substrate of your structure and maybe we can see whats going on. The experiment and the simulation agree because the structure is the same. You can't expect to have a working structure in the field if it doesn't even work in HFSS or CST or AWR or whatever you're simulating in.

Comment: this is a CST one, I shall post by today.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that your material was FR4, and the height between the top and ground layer 1mm , TXLINE gives me 11 ohms, pretty flat, but the width is greater than a quarter wavelenght at 18Ghz, so there will be modes. Also 11 ohms. 5dB return loss is almost exactly what I read out from my smith chart. The correct width for FR4 for 50 ohm should be around 2mm, not 4.3cm.

Also, the bottom (ground layer) should be covering the entire bottom side of the PCB, or fringing effects will destroy the model.

Comment: actually I trying to use it for finding eps and mu complex value of different material. If it is air, should it be 4.3cm?

Comment: Hey, the width of the conductor is 1.44 cm, i used in TXline and found ~48 ohm. 4.3 cm is the box width,not the strpline width.